# How to defer the emission from an Observable based on another event stream?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, dom-events

What would be the operator to make an observable from an array but only emit the next observable value based on the change/count of another event stream, let's say a click?

```
const scroller$ = Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3,4);
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click'); // need help here
scroller$.subscribe(console.log) 

// click // 1

// click // 2

// click // 3

// click // 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `zip` to do that:

```
const scroller$ = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
scroller$.zip(
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click'),
  (value, event) => value // Specify a projection function to ignore the event
).subscribe(console.log);
```

The documentation for `zip` is [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-zipProto), but it's ... a work in progress.

Basically, `zip` combines the values emitted by the input observables in lock-step. So when the first event is emitted, it will be combined and emitted with the first value from `scroller$` and nothing further will be emitted until the second event occurs, etc.

`zip` can be passed a function to project the combined values, so if you are interested only in the value - and not the event - you can use a projection function to ignore the event.

Comment: Is there a simpler, procedural way to write this?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka I don't understand why you'd want to do that, if you are using RxJS. I would say no, there isn't, as it's inherently reactive.

Comment: It helps me understand what is going on, If I see it once in procedural, I can translate it in my mind more easilly, until I develop RxJS way of thinking.

Comment: @cartant yay it works!  is it possible to bind another event to make it go backwards? I'll make another question

Comment: If you want to go backwards, asking another question that explains the fundamental problem you are trying to solve would be a good idea. You likely don't need anything like the code in this answer. Instead, it sounds more like you want to track an offset into an array. A [`scan`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan)-based solution is likely more appropriate.